# tf multiple input and batch input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train 2 input model with mini batch.
When I try batch_size=1, it work well. But if I try to increase batch size(for example, 8), model give me the error shown as below... What am I wrong?

```
"ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 16 input tensors"
```

simplified data generator code:

```
def __getitem__(self,index):

    inputLst,labelLst = [],[]
    for i in range(len(batch_size)):
        input1 = load(input1)
        input2 = load(input2)
        label = load(label)
        inputs = [input1,input2]

        inputLst.append(inputs)
        labelLst.append(label)

    return inputs,label
```

Edit:

From data generator, I got batch size length list as input.

For example, my model need two input which shape are [None,80,80,64,1] and this is a tensor, and feed this as list of tensor.

The input that I received from data generator is a batch size length list of list of tensor.

Now, I just train my model as code below.

```
 for k in range(batch_size):
  with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape:
   generated_img = generator(inputs[k],training=True)
   loss_Gen = Unet_loss(label[k],generated_img)
   gradients_of_generator[k] = 
 gen_tape.gradient(loss_Gen,generator.trainable_variables) 
 mean_gradients = get_mean_gradient(gradient_of_generator)
```

generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(mean_gradients,variables))

Comment: This is a non-functional code so it's impossible to say for sure. For example, where is batch_size defined? If I had to guess, you are appending arrays to an output array, but probably you should be extending instead.

Comment: Batch_size is defined in __init__. Extend also give me same error... may error came from model structure? I tried to give batch size into input layer but still doesn't work...

Comment: You need to show how you are creating tensors and how you are providing them to the model. This code doesn't show any tensors, just a couple lists of lists.